# Generate division factor using Python

Tags: python

I have 2 numbers "a" and "b" where "b" is the division precision.
For example, `a = 10000 and b = 3`, I need `10000/1000`. How can I generate the denominator dynamically using python.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by ```division``` precision

Comment: I need to divide the number by 1<b times zeros>, if precision =1, divide by 10, if 2 divide by 100 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want

```
a = 10000
b = 3
c=int('1'+'0'*b)
print(a,"/",c,'=',a/c)
```

You can also do `10**int(b)`

```
a = 10000
b = 4
c=int(10**b)
print(a,"/",c,'=',a/c)
```

Comment: these are the real hacks, (its horrible I mean)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 10 to the power `b`:

```
>>> a = 10000
>>> b = 3

>>> denominator = 10 ** b
>>> denominator
1000
>>> a / denominator
10.0
```

Comment: @subzero355 glad to be of help! If you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can just create a simple function like;

```
 def division_with_precision(a, b):
        return  a / pow(10, b)
```

and then use it like;

```
division_with_precision(10000, 3)
```